# Is it possible to develop an app that reads other apps' usage data?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-share-extension

With the new app-extension kit, I'd like to know if it's possible to build an app that tracks various usage statistics of other apps. For e.g., the no of times someone uses their calculator or the no of minutes spent on Quora.

Comment: Thank god that such features are not possible on ios. It's nobody's business which apps I use and how often. I love how Apple respects the user's privacy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really nice idea to enhance the ability of iOS system. However, even in iOS8 this is unlike to achieve. Apple has offered so limited APIs for APPs to access other APPs. In those APIs, I cannot find any one to record other APPs' launching or closing. (Except you call that from your own APP so that you can record the time, but this is meaningless.)

In the [official document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/NotificationCenter.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH11-SW1) for App Extension Programming, manager for APP is not a type that is mentioned in the guide. I'm afraid that you have read it and it cannot give you more help.

I tried to do research on the most detail list of iOS APIs to find whether this is possible. But since iOS5.0, Apple no longer provided the API diffs. Here is the [search result](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/search/?q=api).

Comment: This actually sounds like almost the complete opposite of a "really nice idea".